# A function created in Controller gets called twice

Tags: angularjs

I created a page using AngularJS.

```
$scope.search = function (item) {
    if ($scope.searchText == undefined) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        if (item.city.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1 || item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Link :     http://plnkr.co/edit/sDtDyKDw2pPJC5Ww05W4?p=preview

The program runs fine. I set a debugger in the console and checked the function and found that the **search** function in the script is called twice for each (ng-repeat)item. i.e. 10 times in total. What is the reason that it goes around again?

Comment: I suggest create a custom filter and pass like this
`<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | customFilter:searchText">'

Answer (score 0):

Change your filter value as `searchText`

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: searchText" >
   <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
   <td>{{employee.city}}</td>
</tr>

<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{city:searchText}" >
```

Comment: but according to above method it looks like he want to search only in city column..

Comment: But this is not overhead as compared to other methods

Comment: I want to search on both city and name column. The code does that but when checked the console it is seen that the function is called twice for each item. How to stop that?

Comment: @TagHeuer which function?

Comment: $scope.search = function(item)....

add a console.log() to that funciton you can see that it is repeated 10 times.

Comment: why you using that function only need the searchText variable pls remove that

Comment: If I do that then it will search the entire table. But I want to search only on the Name and City column

Answer (score 0):

Not better with this ? :)

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter: searchText" >
```

Or if you want to search only in 'city' column

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{city:searchText}" >
```

Hope it helps.